# <unknown>:0: error: type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift2

Migrating to Swift 3 from 2.3 and am running into this issue. The error is traceable to a view controller.

[image: error]

I do not see any extensions/protocols which would require a 'Key' constrained to 'String'.

I've tried to comment out code that might be causing the error, and have had strange results - ie removing an empty `viewDidLoad()` made the error appear in another class.

I'll update the thread if I make progress.

Comment: Hello Andrew, have you had any luck solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Key is a type inside a structure maybe a struct/class like Dictionary.

Use AnyHashable as Key to replace String if in Dictionary.