# Type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, swift3, compiler-errors

The following file contains the following error:

```
Type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'
```

Without any line numbers.

```
//
//  UserProfile+Util.swift
//  MySampleApp
//
//  Modified on 05/06/2016.
//
//

import AWSMobileHubHelper

extension UserProfile {

    class func getDeviceArn() -> String? {

        let pushManager: AWSPushManager = AWSPushManager.defaultPushManager()



        if let _endpointARN = pushManager.endpointARN {
            // pushManager.enabled = true
            return _endpointARN
        }else{
            pushManager.registerForPushNotifications()
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

As i understand, this error occurs when an extension is used with a 'Key'.
I dont extend a class with a key. This has been driving me crazy for several days.

I'm aware of the following question, but it does not fix my problem: [<unknown>:0: error: type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519477/unknown0-error-type-key-constrained-to-non-protocol-type-string)

Comment: Have you tried setting the extension as public, and/or declaring the func as so... @objc class func getDeviceArn() -> String?

Comment: @TheBasicMind Using 'public extension UserProfile {' will give the following error: 'Extension of internal class cannot be declared public'. I've also tried 'objc class func getDeviceArn()' but it does not make any difference. Still the same error.